# Installshield installer admin requirement

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2011

I'm working with an InstallShield basic MSI installer which has another MSI chained into it as well as a custom action.

Installing our application as an administrator works great, the MSI runs, launches our custom action as well as the chained MSI. 
However if you run it as a non administrative user on Windows 7 you get two UAC elevation prompts (one for the original execution and one for the chained MSI) but the custom action is failing presumably due to a lack of elevation.

I'd like to stop the installer running if the user is not an administrator (we have control over the software environment so I can assume the administrator has UAC off) or ensure this custom action prompts the user for elevation (again) before running.

I've added a condition of "AdminUser" in the general information section using the InstallShield tool (as below) but a non admin user in Windows 7 doesn't get the warning and can install the application.
 [image: Install Conditions]

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For what you're trying to do, you'd need to set the [`MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa816403.aspx). However I would suggest instead just signing both of your .msi files with the same certificate, as in that case Windows Installer will not issue the second UAC prompt.